# Value not initialized in if statement

Tags: java

The below code has a compiler error:

> `speedMsg might not been initialized`

How can I fix that?

```
String speedMsg;

// Determine the grade
if (speed >= 150)
  speedMsg = "STOP! STOP! Please let me OUT!";
else if (speed <= 150)
  speedMsg = "Whew I'll just walk from here Thanks.";
```

Comment: Compiler does not know that your if-elseif covers the whole domain. Hence, is warns that, unless you specify an initial value or an 'else' block, your returned value might be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change to:

```
// Determine the grade
if (speed >= 150)
    speedMsg = "STOP! STOP! Please let me OUT!";
else
    speedMsg = "Whew I'll just walk from here Thanks.";
```

That should be enough to let the compiler be sure the variable will be initialized.

Comment: +1.  As it stands, the `else if` implies that it's possible for neither condition to be hit, and so the variable might be uninitialised.  Since it's clear that one condition or other must be hit, there's no problem making this obvious in the code.

Comment: This solution helped so much I am so happy for this site because my instructor is not good at explaining this. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Replace `else if` with `else` because the compiler then will know that speedMsg will always have a value.

Answer (score 1):

Set:

```
String speedMsg = "";
```

Or remove the else if, change it to an else.

```
if (speed >= 150)
    speedMsg = "STOP! STOP! Please let me OUT!";
else
    speedMsg = "Whew I'll just walk from here Thanks.";
```

Better yet:

```
String speedMsg = speed >= 150 ? 
                    "STOP! STOP! Please let me OUT!" :
                    "Whew I'll just walk from here Thanks.";
```

You're not initializing your string and then attempting to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize speedMsg:

```
String speedMsg = null;
```

That should fix the problem, *speedMsg might not been initialized*.

Comment: Noted @DuncanJones and thanks for not downvoting. Answered on impulse. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include an `else` statement, since the compiler is not smart enough to figure out that you have included all the possibilities of `speed` values in `if` and `if else` statements.

Note that the local variables are the only ones that have no default values and you need to initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `speedMsg` may not be initialized if
`speed >= 150` or `speed <= 150`.

Although it is clear that all possible values for speed are there, Java
has no way to know it.
If, instead of `if else if` you use only `if else`, it will be initialized.

Or you need to initialized to a default error message when you declare it.

Answer (score 0):

> error variable speedMsg might not been initialized

This error messege tells you, that the variable (here: speedMsg) might be **null**. So you can solve the Problem if you set a default worth like this:

```
String speedMsg = "Speed";
```

OR you fix it like this

```
if (speed >= 150)
    speedMsg = "STOP! STOP! Please let me OUT!";
else
    speedMsg = "Whew I'll just walk from here Thanks.";
```

The reason why you get the message is, that eclipse is not able to check if the comparisons in the "if-else if" block is valid and speedMsg will always be set (no default).

IMHO the second solution is more elegant.